# Pass A Variable Pivot Filed Name To Sort VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pivot

I'm working with a pivot table, and am using the following code:

```
Sub SortCTRDescending()
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields("Industry").AutoSort _
        xlDescending, "Total CTR", ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6"). _
        PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(6), 1
End Sub
```

Is there a way to pass the Pivot Field `"Industry"` as a variable depending on what is selected in the pivot table rows? i.e. if Industry changes to "List Name", have the variable set to whatever row label selected (assumes only 1 row label)? These then get passed to a button, which would "sort by CTR" or "sort by Open Rate" where column numbers stay the same.

Edit: Added a screenshot of the data. The Row Label is Industry, but this can change to any of the other fields, how can I make the first row label the primary sorting variable.

[image: Excel sheet]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through the `RowFields` of the PivotTable to find the name of the current field. The code checks to ensure that the table currently has only 1 `RowField`. Make adjustments for your specific object names.

```
Sub SortCTRDescending()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField, pField As PivotField
Dim sField As String

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'change as needed
Set pt = ws.PivotTables("PivotTable6")

If pt.RowFields.Count = 1 Then

    'note that even though there is only one field, the loop is needed to get the name
    For Each pField In pt.RowFields
        sField = pField.Name
    Next

Else

    MsgBox "Whoa! More Than 1 Row Field!"
    Exit Sub

End If

Set pf = pt.PivotFields(sField)

pf.AutoSort xlDescending, "Total CTR", pt.PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(6), 1

End Sub
```

Comment: This assumes that there's a place where the name appears, but it doesn't. So is there a way to parse out the currently active Pivot Field and then maybe pass that value into a range?

Comment: @GregdeLima can you update our question with a screenshot explanation? I don't know what you mean by *currently active Pivot Field*.

Comment: Added the screenshot.

Comment: okay - I see now. give me a moment and I wll update my answer

Comment: had to add `.Count` to the `RowFields = 1`.